Highlight Gantt Chart in plotly
I have created a Gantt chart for some log analysis. I want a feature in it such that when we hover over a plot, the plot should highlight itself to show which plot I am highlighting.
def create_gantt_data(df):
    tasks = {}
    gantt_data = []

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        task = row['FileType']
        start = row['timestamp'].to_pydatetime()  # Convert to Python datetime object
        end = row['Endtime'].to_pydatetime()  # Convert to Python datetime object
        method = row['Method']  # Get the Method column

        if task not in tasks:
            tasks[task] = []

        # Check for overlap
        overlap = False
        for t in tasks[task]:
            if (start < t['end'] and end > t['start']):
                overlap = True
                break
        
        if overlap:
            # Create a new line for overlapping task
            task += " (Overlap)"
            if task not in tasks:
                tasks[task] = []
        
        tasks[task].append({'start': start, 'end': end})
        gantt_data.append(dict(
            Task=task,
            Start=start,
            Finish=end,
            Method=method,
            HoverText=f"Start: {start}<br>End: {end}<br>Method: {method}"
        ))

    return gantt_data

gantt_data = create_gantt_data(df1)

# Create the Gantt chart
fig = ff.create_gantt(gantt_data, index_col='Task', show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True)

I tried to use figure Widget function,but was unable to react the desired goal.


You didn't provide function create_gantt and didn't mention what ff is.
Not knowing what ff is I would suggest to try out either altair-vis or plotly

@dmayilyan ff.create_gantt is from plotly figure_factory which is a basically a collection of more obscure plots. see here

@Pratyush are you using a jupyter notebook?

@Pratyush Please provide code that can be reproduced. I can't reproduce your problem. Have a look at section "Help others reproduce the problem" in How do I ask a good question?

The create_gantt is a built-in function for creating a Gantt chart, and ff is the figure factory that I have imported from Plotly.
Yes I am using a nootbook
